# JavaScript how to apply same complicated function to 2 similar html dropdown block

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using JavaScript to code 2 dropdowns. Same logic will used in them.

```js
function checkboxStatusChange() {
  var multiselect = document.getElementById("mySelectLabel");
  var multiselectOption = multiselect.getElementsByTagName('option')[0];

  var values = [];
  var checkboxes = document.getElementById("mySelectOptions");
  var checkedCheckboxes = checkboxes.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked');

  for (const item of checkedCheckboxes) {
    var checkboxValue = item.getAttribute('value');
    values.push(checkboxValue);
  }

  var dropdownValue = "Nothing is selected";
  if (values.length > 0) {
    dropdownValue = values.join(', ');
  }

  multiselectOption.innerText = dropdownValue;
}

function toggleCheckboxArea(onlyHide = false) {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementById("mySelectOptions");
  var displayValue = checkboxes.style.display;

  if (displayValue != "block") {
    if (onlyHide == false) {
      checkboxes.style.display = "block";
    }
  } else {
    checkboxes.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.multiselect {
  width: 100%;
}

.selectBox {
  position: relative;
}

.selectBox select {
  width: 100%;
}

.overSelect {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.selectOptions {
  display: none;
  border: 0.5px #7c7c7c solid;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.selectOptions label {
  display: block;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  min-height: 1.2em;
  background-color: #ffffff00;
  padding: 0 2.25rem 0 .75rem;
  /* padding: .375rem 2.25rem .375rem .75rem; */
}

.selectOptions label:hover {
  background-color: #1e90ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
    <label>Custom multiselect one</label>

    <div id="myMultiselect" class="multiselect">
      <div id="mySelectLabel" class="selectBox" onclick="toggleCheckboxArea()">
        <select class="form-control input-sm col-xs-1">
          <option>select servicer</option>
        </select>
        <div class="overSelect"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="mySelectOptions" class="selectOptions">
        <label for="one"><input type="checkbox" id="one" onchange="checkboxStatusChange()" value="First checkbox" />First checkbox</label>
        <label for="two"><input type="checkbox" id="two" onchange="checkboxStatusChange()" value="Second checkbox" />Second checkbox</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
    <label>Custom multiselect two</label>

    <div id="newMultiselect" class="multiselect">
      <div id="newSelectLabel" class="selectBox" onclick="toggleCheckboxArea()">
        <select class="form-control input-sm col-xs-1">
          <option>select servicer</option>
        </select>
        <div class="overSelect"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="newSelectOptions" class="selectOptions">
        <label for="one"><input type="checkbox" id="newone" onchange="checkboxStatusChange()" value="New First checkbox" />First checkbox</label>
        <label for="two"><input type="checkbox" id="newtwo" onchange="checkboxStatusChange()" value="New Second checkbox" />Second checkbox</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The issue is instead of code another similar JavaScript function, I have no idea ,how to modify apply the same one and apply to the second dropdown.

Any friend can help ?

Comment: Is there something preventing you from putting an 'onchange' function on your selects?